# IronPython unable to see certain classes in my Assembly

Tags: ironpython

Im having trouble using some of the classes in my Assembly from IronPython. This is the line I am using in my script:

```
from Comet.Pricing.Parsing import RegexLookupMapper
```

The class is defined as:

```
public class RegexLookupMapper<T> : SingleValueMapper<string, T>
```

I have no problem importing another class in that Assembly:

```
from Comet.Pricing.Parsing import QuoteRequest
```

The class is declared as follows:

```
public class QuoteRequest<T> : IQuoteRequest<T> where T : IInstrument
```

When I do a dir on Comet.Pricing.Parsing there are a lot less classes than are actually in the assembly. The only thing I can see in common with all the missing classes is that they all derive from:

```
SingleValueMapper<string, T>
```

which derives from a class in another namespace/assembly (which has also been imported with no problems).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out a dependency of a base class was missing.